Incorrect number received by smart contract
When deploying sendNumber.ts script
import { toNano } from 'ton-core';
import { Counter } from '../wrappers/Counter';
import { compile, NetworkProvider } from '@ton-community/blueprint';

export async function run(provider: NetworkProvider) {
    const counter = provider.open(
        Counter.createFromConfig({}, await compile('Counter'))
    );

    await counter.sendNumber(provider.sender(), toNano('0.01'), 123n);
    console.log('Sent number: ', await counter.getTotal());

}

Upon running npx blueprint run
I get a return value of "Sent number:  15322573764n"
Where it's supposed to be Sent number: 123n
upon resetting the smart contract to 0, and redeploying again, I once again get a random
11 digit number starting with 1
here is the wrapper code for the function definitions "Counter.ts":
export class Counter implements Contract {
    constructor(
        readonly address: Address,
        readonly init?: { code: Cell; data: Cell }
    ) {}
...................
async sendNumber(
        provider: ContractProvider,
        via: Sender,
        value: bigint,
        number: bigint
    ) {
        await provider.internal(via, {
            value,
            sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
            body: beginCell().storeUint(number, 32).endCell(),
        });
    }

counter.fc (no errors here as far as I know)
#include "imports/stdlib.fc";

() recv_internal(int my_balance, int msg_value, cell in_msg_full, slice in_msg_body) impure {
    throw_if(35, in_msg_body.slice_bits() < 32);

    int n = in_msg_body~load_uint(32);

    slice ds = get_data().begin_parse();
    int total = ds~load_uint(64);

    total += n;

    set_data(begin_cell().store_uint(total, 64).end_cell());
}

int get_total() method_id {
    slice ds = get_data().begin_parse();
    int total = ds~load_uint(64);

    return total;
}

